# How to display HTML response on DOM, returned by an API call?

Tags: html, reactjs, frontend

My API call returns the below html response and I want to render it on the DOM as a html tags, not as just text with html tags.

API response :  `<strong>Hello</strong>`

How its rendering on DOM :   `<strong>Hello</strong>`

How I'm expecting it to render on DOM :  **Hello**

Comment: Check my answer. Happy coding :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use [dangerouslySetInnerHTML](https://fr.reactjs.org/docs/dom-elements.html#dangerouslysetinnerhtml)

Comment: Thanks Joris . Apart from this is there any other way I can achieve this?

Comment: It's the React recommended way but you can the node yourself and add it to the dom:

```js
const myContent = document.createElement('div');
myContent.innerHTML = "<strong>Hello</strong>";

document.body.appendChild(myContent);

```

Answer (score 1):

You can use [react-html-parser](https://github.com/wrakky/react-html-parser)

```sh
npm install react-html-parser
```

```js
import React from 'react';
import ReactHtmlParser from "react-html-parser"

const htmlString = '<strong>Hello</strong>';

function App() {
  return (
    <div>
        {ReactHtmlParser(htmlString)}
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Demo: [React HTML Parser Example](https://replit.com/@rommyarb/React-HTML-Parser-Example)

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve it using; `html-react-parser`

Do following steps:

```
npm install react-html-parser
# or 
yarn add react-html-parser
```

Import or require the module:

```
// ES Modules
import parse from 'html-react-parser';

// CommonJS
const parse = require('html-react-parser');
```

Make sure to render parsed adjacent elements under a parent element:

```
<>
  {parse(`<strong>Hello</strong>`)}
</>
```

Happy coding :)

Answer (score 0):

Another way is to use innerHTML:

```
var APIResponse = '<strong>Hello</strong>';
document.getElementById("target").innerHTML = APIResponse;
```

Resource: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/innerHTML

Comment: This is a very dangerous approach likely to clash with React's own DOM updating logic.